# Perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory

The question given to me:

**a**. Find the *perfect numbers* between $1$ and $10^6$

**b**: Find the *abundant numbers* between $1$ and $1000$

---

For **a**, I wrote

```
Select[Range[1, 10^6], All]
```

I think I'm suppose to use divisor in there somewhere, but I'm not sure where to put that since I think me selecting all the numbers between $1$ and $10^6$ won't give me the list of all the perfect numbers...

For **b**, I think it's similar to part **a**, which I'm in a dead end with.

---

I'm trying to find a simple input since I'm still a beginner and want to stay with the basics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perfect numbers:

```
Select[ Range[10^6], Total[Divisors @ #] == 2 # &]
```

> ```
> {6, 28, 496, 8128}
> ```

abundant numbers:

```
Select[ Range[10^3], Total[ Most @ Divisors @ #] > # &]//Short
```

> ```
> { 12, 18, 20, 24, 30, 36, 40, 42, 48, <<228>>, 
>      968, 972, 978, 980, 984, 990, 992, 996, 1000}
> ```

I used `Short` to to get only a few since there are:

```
Count[ Range[10^3], _?(Total[Most@Divisors@#] > # &)]
```

> ```
> 246
> ```

of them.

**Edit**

As RunnyKine pointed out that using `DivisorSigma[1, #] &` is more efficient than `Total @ Divisors @ # &`. Another improvement might be exploiting the fact that there are no known odd perfect numbers, it was verified that there is none below `10^1500`. The largest known perfect number (`48`-th)  has only `34850340` digits i.e. `IntegerLength[2^(57885161 - 1) (2^57885161 - 1)]`. Taking the above into account we get `2` times speed up with:

```
Pick[ #, DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 #, 0]& @ Range[2, 10^6, 2]
```

However we can observe there are odd abundant numbers, but they are sparsely distributed among even ones. Below `1000` there is only one ( while there are `245` even ones):

```
Pick[ #, UnitStep[ DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 # - 1], 1]& @ Range[1, 10^3, 2]
```

> ```
> {945}
> ```

Below `10^6` there are

```
Length @ Pick[ #, UnitStep[ DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 # - 1], 1] & /@ 
{Range[ 2, 10^6, 2], Range[ 1, 10^6, 2]}
```

> ```
> {245549, 1996}
> ```

even and odd abundant numbers respectively.

It is remarkable that `Length @ Pick[ Range[10^6], UnitStep[ DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 # - 1], 1]]` is faster than : `Count[ Range[10^6], _?(DivisorSigma[1, #] > 2 # &)]`.

Comment: Good stuff. I wonder if there's any odd perfect numbers.

Comment: @RunnyKine Many have asked this question for centuries. Check out [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPerfectNumber.html) or http://www.oddperfect.org/

Comment: I just started learning this information, but what exactly does @ do?

Comment: @asik `f @ x` is equivalent to `f[x]`, another possible form is `x//f`. Read e.g. [Special Ways to Input Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html) tutorial in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Kept seeing it, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 10):

A faster approach to finding **Perfect** numbers using `DivisorSigma`

```
 Select[Range[10^6], DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 # &]
```

> {6, 28, 496, 8128}

Here's an even faster approach:

```
Pick[#, MapThread[Equal, {DivisorSigma[1, #], 2 #}], True] &[Range[10^6]]
```

and a little bit faster:

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 #, 0] &@Range[10^6]
```

For **Abundant** numbers do:

```
Select[Range[10^6], (DivisorSigma[1, #] - #) > # &]
```

and a faster approach as above:

```
Pick[#, MapThread[Greater, {DivisorSigma[1, #] - #, #}], True] &[Range[10^6]]
```

By giving `Greater` the `Listable` `Attribute` we can squeeze out some more performance:

```
SetAttributes[Greater, Listable]
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] > 2 #, True] &@Range[10^6]
```

**Edit :**

For this particular problem since we know that the largest **Perfect** number is less than `10000`, we can begin to hit miliseconds regime using `ParallelMap`:

```
ParallelMap[Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 #, 0] &, {Range[2, 5*^3, 2], 
    Range[5*^3 + 2, 1*^4, 2]}] // Flatten // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.015627, {6, 28, 496, 8128}}

Of course this will also give us speed up if we scan the entire range.

Comment: A little faster yet: `Pick[#, Unitize[DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 #], 0] &@Range[10^6]`

Comment: @MichaelE2. Nice, but almost the same time as the `MapThread` method on my machine.

Comment: On mine it's 4.7 (MapThread) to 4.2.

Comment: @MichaelE2, it's definitely a little bit faster.

Comment: @MichaelE2, You actually don't need `Unitize` and that makes it a tiny bit faster.

Comment: D'oh. Of course. Thanks.  I used `UnitStep` for the abundant and didn't think.

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks for leading me to the idea.

Answer (score 9):

Or how about the connection between even perfect numbers and Mersenne primes?

```
With[{p = Prime[Range[20]]},
     Pick[p, PrimeQ[2^p - 1]] /. q_ -> 2^(q - 1) (2^q - 1)]
```

**Update** for perfect numbers only.

As noted in previous answers, `DivisorSigma[1,n]` is faster than summing `Divisors`, and `Pick` is faster than `Select`. So even perfect numbers may be found by using

```
RepeatedTiming[Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] - 2 #, 0] &@Range[2, 10^6, 2]]
```

which gives a timing of 1.34 s on my machine. These approaches are slow compared to the clever divisor sum by @MichaelE2. The repeated timing of his function is a tiny 0.056 s.

@QuantumDot points out the new v10.4 functions `PerfectNumber[n]` and `PerfectNumberQ[n]`. However, the following takes a **glacial** 4 seconds! Why?

```
RepeatedTiming[Pick[#, Map[PerfectNumberQ, #]] &@Range[2, 10^6, 2]]
```

The Help page for the new v10.4 function `MersennePrimeExponent` shows how to instantly calculate even perfect numbers.

```
RepeatedTiming[2^(# - 1)*(2^# - 1) &[MersennePrimeExponent[Range[4]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

`DivisorSigma` is no doubt fast on individual integers, but the problem of finding the sum of divisors over a large contiguous range of integers can be solved with a fast a C-style program, perfect for compiling if the sums stay within the size of a machine integer.

The idea is to turn the problem of summing the divisors around.  An integer `n` is a divisor of each of its multiples.  We keep a list of sums, and for every integer `n`, we add it to each sum whose position in the list is a multiple of `n`.  We do this up to some pre-specified limit `lim`.  At the end, the list contains the sums of the divisors of each integer up to `lim`.

```
divsum = Compile[{{lim, _Integer}},
   Module[{dsum},
    dsum = Table[1, {lim}];
    Do[
     dsum[[k]] += n,
     {n, 2, lim}, {k, n, lim, n}];
    dsum],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

divsum[10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.119278, Null} *)

DivisorSigma[1, Range[10^6]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.985526, Null} *)
```

We can define functions to find perfect and abundant numbers, using `Pick` to pick out the numbers according to the divisor-sum property.

```
perfect[lim_] := Pick[#, divsum[lim] - 2 #, 0] &@Range[lim];
abundant[lim_] := Pick[#, UnitStep[2 # - divsum[lim]], 0] &@Range[lim]

perfect[10^6] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.159563, {6, 28, 496, 8128}} *)

abundant[10^6] // Short // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.168468, {12, 18, 20, 24, <<247537>>, 999992, 999996, 999999, 1000000}} *)
```

Comment: Do you know why the alternate line
`Do[dsum[[Range[n, lim, n]]] += n, {n, 2, lim}]` is 3 times faster than
`Do[dsum[[k]] += n, {n, 2, lim}, {k, n, lim, n}]` in an uncompiled version
of divsum, and yet 7 times slower in a compiled version of divsum?

Comment: @KennyColnago The one is faster in the uncompiled version because `Part` is "vectorized", but I'm not sure why it's so much slower in the compiled version.  Its compiled code is 75% longer than the other's, which may contribute some.  It could be that the vectorized read/write (with `..[[list]]`) is slower than single element read/write when compiled.  I have to go, but perhaps if I think of something, I'll let you know.

Comment: @KennyColnago First, `Do[r = Range[n, lim, n]; dsum[[r]] += n, {n, 2, lim}]` is a little more efficient, with compiled code similar to my code, but still much slower.  Examining the C code (`CCodeGenerate`) of each shows mine has rather simple, direct C array addressing -- probably impossible to beat for speed.  In the other loop, library functions are called to deal with the list of parts, one to get the parts and another to set the parts.  This is the main difference in the code, and I suppose must account for the difference in speed.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the sleuthing! It helps a lot with my never ending search for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

With the newly released version [10.4](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html), you can use the built-in function [`PerfectNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PerfectNumber.html).

I don't have the latest version of 10.4; it would be nice to see how it compares with the answers given here...

---

but... based on my reading of the documentation page (under the section Details), I can only conclude one thing:  `PerfectNumber` is bloatware.  Arguments contrary to my conclusion are welcome in the comments section.

Comment: Can you elaborate why the new built-in `PerfectNumber` function is bloatware?

Comment: @shrx In my view, there are just a small handful of known perfect numbers so the function should be part of a separate package rather than littering the `System` context namespace.  The implementation of that function may as well be a table of known values, since I'd imagine finding new ones on a personal computer is hopeless.