# Strange Behavior when making Equal Listable in Pick

Tags: functions, evaluation, attributes

While trying to make this [problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34375/perfect-numbers/34377#34377) more efficient I tried different methods and dabbled with making `Greater` and `Equal` `Listable`. To my surprise, while `Greater` worked as expected, `Equal` on the other hand showed a strange behavior. Let's dig deeper:

First let's look at `Greater`

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] > 2 #] &@Range[6]
```

Gives the error:

```
Pick::incomp: Expressions {1,2,3,4,5,6} and {1,3,4,7,6,12}>{2,4,6,8,10,12} have incompatible 
shapes. >>
```

Now we make `Greater` `Listable`

```
SetAttributes[Greater, Listable]
```

And we can now evaluate the above command successfully

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] > 2 #] &@Range[20]
```

> {12, 18, 20}

Okay, let's move on to `Equal`

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 #] &@Range[8]
```

> Sequence[]

We now make `Equal` `Listable`

```
SetAttributes[Equal, Listable]
Attributes[Equal]
```

> {Listable, Protected}

Now let's try again:

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 #] &@Range[8]
```

> Sequence[]

Hmmm, what's going on here?

Well, let's explicitly provide the list and see what happens:

```
Pick[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
 DivisorSigma[1, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}] == 2 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}]
```

> {6}

Interesting, this works!

okay now let's textually substitute using `With`, this should technically be the same thing right?

```
With[{p = Range[8]}, Pick[p, DivisorSigma[1, p] == 2*p]]
```

> Sequence[]

I guess not.

Finally, let's look at `Trace`. I'll shorten the input list here.

First with explicit input of list:

```
Pick[{4, 5, 6}, DivisorSigma[1, {4, 5, 6}] == 2 {4, 5, 6}] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Pick[Range[4, 6], DivisorSigma[1, Range[4, 6]] == 2 Range[4, 6]] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see that only in the explicit case does `Equal` act `Listable`
What is going on here? Sorry about the tiny images.

Comment: @PinguinDirk. I have a workaround that works if you look at my answer in the link. Just wondering why `greater` works but `Equal` doesn't work properly.

Comment: I think this is related to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/862). `Range` gives a packed array, for which `Equal` has special handling which bypasses the main evaluator.

Comment: I missed this question before but I agree with what @Simon wrote.  Simon, do you care to post that as an answer?  I think someone should.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a manifestation of the issue raised in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/862), that `Equal` for packed arrays is handled in a non-standard way, causing the `Listable` attribute to be ignored.

`Range[8]` returns a packed array, so for that case the non-standard evaluation kicks in. But the explicitly entered list `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}` is not a packed array, so you get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

My original answer posted below was a naive misunderstanding.

However,

For what its worth (apologies again for previous misconception):

```
SetAttributes[Equal, Listable]
Pick[#, Release@(Hold[DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 #])] &@Range[8]
```

works...

**OLD**

```
Pick[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 #] &@Range[8]
```

your test applies to elements whereas you expect your Pick to apply to list.
When you 'replace' # with list it works.

Note (for illustration purposes):

```
Function[x, Pick[x, DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 # & /@ x]][Range[8]]
```

works.

In contrast the following works without modification:

```
Select[#, DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 # &] &@Range[8]
```

or

```
Cases[#, _?(DivisorSigma[1, #] == 2 # &)] &@Range[8]
```

Comment: Actually, the point is that if you put the list explicitly it works. You can see that it works with `Greater` only when you make `Greater` `Listable`, note that I made `Equal` `Listable`. Also look at the `Trace` to see what's happening.

Comment: apologies, I take your point and as such have learned something, however i believe we are making the same point despite my poor explanation...when Greater is make listable the second argument of of `Pick` is a list of True,False from Pick will select. I apologise for not appreciating that you made Equal listable and hence your dilemma...rendering Equal listable for test produces desired list outside Pick but malfunctions inside Pick...